# Is it possible to dynamically create a conveyor network at runtime?

Tags: anylogic

I am currently attempting to construct a data driven warehouse simulation where all my racks are generated at runtime from a db. The picking racks are adjacent to a one large conveyor, which leads to a network of conveyors.

I have the data on the dimensions and relative location of the conveyors, and want to avoid manually building them if possible, given that the conveyors' parameters are among the decision variables.

Is there a way of creating a conveyor network using the material handling library at runtime with parameters mapped to a db? Or do I have to create a custom agent?

Thanks

Comment: here is the answer to your question: https://www.anylogic.com/blog/how-to-build-a-true-digital-twin/

Comment: thx for sharing @Felipe. Any questions on the details, let me know ;)

Comment: Thank you Felipe for sharing and thank you Benjamin for creating the webinar. This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hello @Benjamin, quick question - how would you go about creating curved conveyors using the method presented in the webinar? I am currently adding segments to conveyor agents using a database of points, but I can't seem to find a way of creating curved MarkupSegments in the same manner.

Comment: @Shingston, best always open new issues for new specific questions. Not sure about this one. If the API lets you create/edit conveyors before initialializing, that is the way. If not, it may not be possible.